# How to make a global property (setter and getter)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I need to create an object for example `NSString` and let other classes get/set the value for it.

thx. for help :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Global variables are not a sign of good class design.

Comment: @Pfitz so what u suggest to do ?

Comment: @Omarj try to rethink your class design and avoid global variables.

Comment: Pass the object as a parameter to the other objects who need access to it. Maybe if you explain exactly what you need we'll be able to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to attach the value as a property to a singleton instance of some class. One singleton instance that already exists in your application is the application delegate. So, just add an `NSString` property to your application delegate and you can access it from any class in your app (as long as you `#import` your application delegate).

In your application delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString* someString;
```

In your other classes:

```
[self doSomethingWithAString:((YourAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).someString];
```

Comment: i don't need to use application delegate .

Comment: No, you don't, but it's easier than having to create your own singleton class for just one object.

Comment: did this effect on application performance cause i have more than one variable and need retrieve it more than one ???

Comment: No there is no difference in performance using this technique

Answer (score 1):

Create a Singleton/Shared class.

```
@implementation SINGLETON

static SINGLETON *instance = nil;

+(SINGLETON*)sharedInstance{
    @synchronized(self) {   
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[SINGLETON alloc] init];
        }
        return instance;
    }
 }
```

EDIT:

This will come handy... [Objective-C Singleton problem. Object recognized in one class but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631940/objective-c-singleton-problem-object-recognized-in-one-class-but-not-another)

Comment: this one just allow to me retrieve value Not set ??

Comment: it is not allow to do it like u say go and try it and you will see what i mean.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Your class method always returns nil. Fix it.